# Kids in wagons probability

Tags: probability

$11$ kids get on a train with $3$ wagons. What's the probability that in the $1$st wagon there are exactly $3$ kids? Isn't this the same with saying $x_1+x_2+x_3=11$ and $x_1=3$? If yes, how could one solve this?

Comment: Well, count the ways to choose three kids.  Then, the probability that those three go to $W_1$ is $\left( \frac 13 \right)^3$ and the probability that the others do not is $\left( \frac 23 \right)^8$.

Comment: It is not the same as saying $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 11$ with $x_1 = 3$ since children are not identical.  Try to implement the strategy outlined by @lulu.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, it's the same, but neither question has enough information to answer it. You don't give the underlying probability distribution, so we can't evaluate the probability.

The "natural" choice of underlying distribution might be different depending on your two presentations of the question. In the $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 =11$ presentation, it might be natural to stipulate that all valid choices of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ are equally likely. In the children presentation, it might be natural to stipulate that *for each child*, getting onto any of the three trains is equally likely -- that's a different underlying distribution.

Assuming that that is the distribution in question, the children problem can be solved by noting that the probability of any specific setup in which 3 children are on the first train and 8 are on one of the other two is $\left(\frac13\right)^3\left(\frac23\right)^8$, and then multiplying this by the number of ways we can have 3 children on the first train, which is equivalent to the number of ways to choose 3 from 11, $\binom{11}3$.

Comment: thank you got it now,if I'm told 2 in first wagon 5 second and 9 in third I use the multinomial distribution?

Comment: @Lola Assuming I'm right about the assumptions of the question, yes, but the assumptions should really be clarified.

Comment: well that's why I don't know how to solve it either because I'm not sure whether I can see the kids as equally likely or not.The problem doesn't specify this clearly

Comment: @Lola Then you don't have enough information to solve the problem, and that is that. Obviously there will be a different probability under the assumption I stated vs. under the assumption (for example) that once 4 kids fill one wagon, the kids will choose a spot in a different wagon.